# Using Objective-c classes in Swift Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have forced to use some classes of objective-c language in swift recently, I have searched and found this [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> To import Objective-C code into Swift from the same target
>
> 1) In your Objective-C bridging header file, import every Objective-C
>   header you want to expose to Swift. For example:
>
> ```
> #import "XYZCustomCell.h"
> #import "XYZCustomView.h"
> #import "XYZCustomViewController.h"
> ```
>
> 2) In Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header
>   build setting under has a path to the bridging header file. The path
>   should be relative to your project, similar to the way your Info.plist
>   path is specified in Build Settings. In most cases, you should not
>   need to modify this setting.
>
> Any public Objective-C headers listed in
>   this bridging header file will be visible to Swift. The Objective-C
>   functionality will be available in any Swift file within that target
>   automatically, without any import statements. Use your custom
>   Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use with system
>   classes.

I followed steps and added initial code to my swift class:

```
let percentageView: FSPercentageView = FSPercentageView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 65, 300, 300))
```

But I got an error with message: Used of undeclared type 'FSPercentageView'.

I have searched this error related using objective-c in swift but I did not find any useful answer.
I checked the bridge header file path and It seems to be fine.

I hope your suggestion fix my problem.

**UPDATE:**

My Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "FSPercentageView.h"
```

My Class of FSPercentageView.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "MCCore.h"

@class FCPercentageView;

typedef enum {
    FSPercentageViewTextStyleAutomaticShowsPercentage,
    FSPercentageViewTextStyleUserDefined
} FSPercentageViewTextStyle;



@interface FSPercentageView : MCNewCustomLayeredView

/*
 Sets the percentage of the view.
 */
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat percentage;

/*
 Sets the percentage of the view.
 */
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat initialPercentage;

/*
 Defines the border percentage for both filled and unfilled portions.
 */
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat borderPercentage;

/*
 The label of the text in the center of the doughnut.
 */
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *textLabel;

/*
 The color for the filled portion of the doughnut.
 */
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *fillColor;

/*
 The color for the unfilled portion of the doughnut.
 */
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *unfillColor;
}
```

and the initial segment of FSPercentageView.m:

```
#import "FSPercentageView.h"
#import "FSNewCustomLayeredView+FSCustomLayeredViewSubclass.h"

typedef enum {
    FSPercentageViewStateNormal,
    FSPercentageViewStatePushed
} FSPercentageViewTouchState;

@interface FSPercentageView()

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *centerView;
@property (nonatomic) FSPercentageViewTouchState touchState;

@end

@implementation FSPercentageView

- (void)setDefaults
{
    [super setDefaults];

    self.linePercentage                 = 0.15;
    self.borderPercentage               = 0;
    self.showTextLabel                  = YES;
    self.animationDuration              = 0.5;
    self.unfillColor                    = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];
    self.borderColorForFilledArc        = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.borderColorForUnfilledArc      = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.borderPercentageForFilledArc   = -1;
    self.borderPercentageForUnfilledArc = -1;
    self.adjustsFontSizeAutomatically   = YES;
    self.roundedImageOverlapPercentage  = 0;
    self.touchState                     = FSPercentageViewStateNormal;
    self.gradientColor1                 = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultBlueColor];
    self.gradientColor2                 = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];

    _percentage                         = 0.0;
    _initialPercentage                  = 0.0;

    _centerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _textLabel   = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}

- (void)willDrawSublayers
{
    if (!self.fillColor) {
        self.fillColor = self.tintColor;
    }
}

- (Class)classForSublayers {
    return [MCSliceLayer class];
}
```

and the swift code:

```
 let percentageView: FSPercentageView = FSPercentageView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 35, 289, 311))
```

Shows the error in above line.

Comment: Show more of your code. Show the bridging header. Show the file where FSPercentageView is declared.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to see my book, which I think is rather clearer on this than Apple's documentation is: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#SECbilingual

Comment: FSPercentageView.h should end with `@end`, not curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope your suggestion fix my problem.

But you have not given any information, so no suggestion is possible. What Apple says is true; I assure you that this feature does work. The problem can only be that you have not followed the directions that you yourself have quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem which my code has.

I have two targets in my app and also I am using Test Unit.
Because of adding my swift code in all mentioned targets, the project was needed to have 3 bridging class related to each target and also the headers must be imported in all of them. Actually the red message was about unit test bridging file.

Right now, I removed my swift class from Test Unit and The code is compiling and running without any problem.